# "Do not localize" warning after choosing file in Tkinter file dialog

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

What I'm trying to achieve is automatically plot data from files, following is my thought:

1. Create a simple GUI using Tkinter, place some buttons to activate functions.
2. define read_file() to select files with tkinter file dialog, and store data.
3. plot with matplotlib.

And here is the simple version of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk

def read_files():
    import tkinter.filedialog as tkf
    filePath = tkf.askopenfilenames()
    with open(filePath, 'r') as file:
        content = file.read()
    # after some lines of code, get data from content
    # data[0] and data[1] are x and y, respectively
    return data

def plot_data():
    data = read_files()
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(data[0], data[1])
    plt.show()

#simple GUI
root.tk()
btn = tk.Button(root, ...(some args), command=plot_data)
btn.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

My code works fine, it can read file and plot data, but here is the problem: every time I clicked "Open" after choosing a file, the file dialog is not closed, and a strange window says "Do not localize" prompted with my data plot, as shown in the pictures.

[image]

It should be noted that if I comment out plt.show() and only print data, this warning disappears.

```
def plot_data():
    data = read_files()
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(data[0], data[1])
    #plt.show()
    print(data)
```

I hope I make myself clear, how can I get rid of this annoying window?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, simply by adding a line of code beneath `import matplotlib` AND above `import matplotlib.xxx`:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")    # Add in here
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```